# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'dict' and 'int'

Tags: python, dictionary

I get the error in the title when I run the following code.

```
amount = int(input('How many packs do you want?'))

pack = {'nuts':4.0,
        'bolts':300.0,
        'screws':140.0,
        'wire(m)':3.5}

for key,val in pack.items():
    total = pack * amount
    print(total,key)
```

I assume that this is because the values in the dictionary are not integer's. how do I fix my code so it doesn't give me this error.

It should print the number of things the person would receive, for example, if someone ordered 2 packs it would print:

8.0 nuts
600.0 bolts
280.0 screws
7.0 wire(m)

Comment: what should multiplying a dictionary by an integer produce?

Comment: It would show the number of things the person would receive, for example, if someone ordered 2 packs they would get back 600 bolts. Mu nailed the question. I will edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calculating the `total` wrong, you need to multiply with `val` and not with pack (which is a dict). Use the below instead (`total = val * amount` instead of `total = pack * amount`):

```
for key,val in pack.items():
    total = val * amount
    print(total,key)
```

So no, the reason is not that the values in the dictionary are not integers.

Answer (score 1):

It is because type(pack) is `<class 'dict'>` and type(amount) is `<class 'int'>`.

There is no methods available in class 'dict' that can do multiplication operation with integer type.

So as mentioned by mu you should multiply it by val.